# How to plot graph y=1/x or y=x^2

Tags: math-software, matlab, graphing-functions

*I am using Octave but I think it applies to MatLab too, so I'm tagging this MatLab since there isnt a Octave tag*

When I do

```
x=linspace(-5,5,25)
y=1/x
```

I get

> error: operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x25)

Or

```
x=linspace(-5,5,25)
y=x^2
```

I get

> error: for A^b, A must be square

How can I then plot the graphs of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x=linspace(-5,5,25)
y = 1./x
plot(x,y)

x=linspace(-5,5,25)
y=x.^2
figure
plot(x,y)
```